# PHP Curl & htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, curl, if-statement, request

i have a question about PHP curl & .htaccess.

My index.php file:

```
<?php
      if(!isset($_GET['q'])){
     } 
      else {
     $q=$_GET['q']; 
     }
    $url = "http://81.83.192.124:8080/".@$q;


    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    print $result;
 ?>
```

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([abc][^/]+) index.php?q=$1
```

The intentions is, when i go to `http://example.org/NL/` i go with the curl to:
`http://81.83.192.124:8080/NL/`

So far i am, but when i click on a link, i doesn't work further.
Who can help me?

Comment: I don't think you can...

Comment: @Charlie Pigarelli my webhosting company say it is possible with the curl function

Comment: I'm not really expert in this but i just think that if a localhost could became a legit domain than there would be no domain purchaser at all...

Comment: it is a business-webserver. my hosting company have no problems with it, because the script have a great cpu load

Answer (score 2):

So your code is acting as a proxy of sorts for 81.83.192.124:8080? You'll run into a few issues. First, links with absolute paths would have to be rewritten. Second, you'll have to capture cookies in both directions if the underlying site requires them to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is here...

```
RewriteRule ^([abc][^/]+) index.php?q=$1
```

should be more like this...

```
RewriteRule ^([abc][^/]+)/$ index.php?q=$1
```

see if that works for you

Comment: i doesnt work.
Not Found

The requested URL /NL/ was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache/2 Server at test.ttb-ltd.eu Port 80